# LoadError: type DataFrame has no field x

Tags: julia, pmap

I have converted a perfectly working `map` into a `pmap`

```
squashed_groups = pmap(group ->
                       reduce(squash,
                              DataFrame(eltypes(o), names(o), 0),
                              eachrow(group)
                             ),
                       groups)
```

Apart from the fact that it doesn't seem to engage in any parallelism -- but I will concede that the groups are mostly small -- I get the following error

```
ERROR: LoadError: type DataFrame has no field x
Stacktrace:
 [1] copy!(::Array{DataFrames.AbstractDataFrame,1}, ::Base.Generator{Array{DataFrames.AbstractDataFrame,1},DataFrames.##34#35{Base.##569#571}}) at ./abstractarray.jl:572
 [2] _collect(::Type{DataFrames.AbstractDataFrame}, ::Base.Generator{Array{DataFrames.AbstractDataFrame,1},DataFrames.##34#35{Base.##569#571}}, ::Base.HasShape) at ./array.jl:363
 [3] map(::Base.##569#571, ::DataFrames.GroupApplied) at /Users/morpheu5/.julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/groupeddataframe/grouping.jl:184
 [4] maptwice(::Function, ::Channel{Any}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame, ::Vararg{DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame,N} where N) at ./asyncmap.jl:188
 [5] wrap_n_exec_twice(::Channel{Any}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.Distributed.##204#207{WorkerPool}, ::Function, ::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame, ::Vararg{DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame,N} where N) at ./asyncmap.jl:154
 [6] #async_usemap#553(::Function, ::Void, ::Function, ::##9#10, ::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame, ::Vararg{DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame,N} where N) at ./asyncmap.jl:103
 [7] (::Base.#kw##async_usemap)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#async_usemap, ::Function, ::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame, ::Vararg{DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame,N} where N) at ./<missing>:0
 [8] (::Base.#kw##asyncmap)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#asyncmap, ::Function, ::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame) at ./<missing>:0
 [9] #pmap#203(::Bool, ::Int64, ::Void, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Void, ::Function, ::WorkerPool, ::Function, ::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame) at ./distributed/pmap.jl:126
 [10] pmap(::WorkerPool, ::Function, ::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame) at ./distributed/pmap.jl:101
 [11] #pmap#213(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame) at ./distributed/pmap.jl:156
 [12] pmap(::Function, ::DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame) at ./distributed/pmap.jl:156
 [13] include_from_node1(::String) at ./loading.jl:569
 [14] include(::String) at ./sysimg.jl:14
 [15] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:305
 [16] _start() at ./client.jl:371
```

I couldn't figure out that that means. I even checked for any places where I could have used an `x` somewhere and changed those, but the error message doesn't change. The inner reduce is a bit complicated, but works using the non-parallel `map` -- as in, it produces the expected result.

Is this a case of me having read all the docs and having understood none of them, or is this a bug somewhere in Julia? I'm running 0.6.0 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0.

Comment: Could you post the definitions of `squash`, `o` and `groups`? So we can reproduce that.

Comment: That would definitely help.